# Как обязать точку в конце строки с помощью регулярных выражений?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Имеется регулярное выражение `r'^[A-Za-z0-9_]{3,16}\Z'`. Что нужно добавить, чтобы оно обязывало ставить одну точку в конце строки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно пойти по простому пути - просто добавить точку

```
r'^[A-Za-z0-9_]{3,16}\.\Z'
```

Но ее нужно "заэскейпить", так как просто точка - это спецсимвол, который значит "любой символ" (ну почти любой).

Comment: Экранировать это называется по-русски )

Comment: Тоже поумничаю в комментарии: `[A-Za-z0-9_]` эквивалентно `\w` =)

Comment: экранировать и заэскейпить может быть разными вещами